# Python multithreading: How to create a sequencial thread in every while iteration to process something

Tags: python, multithreading

The purpose of both async methods and threads is to make it possible to process several tasks concurrently.

But I have a task that I need to run threads in a sequencial manner that process some strings, and I don't have any idea how to do it.

The step by step will be as follows:

1. If condition is not met
2. Create a new thread
3. Executes a process_something_function that alters the condition
4. await all the processing on this thread to finish
5. Put this thread to sleep
6. Verify if the condition is met
7. If is met, end the code and print the condition, if is not repeat all the above.

On a coding manner, will be like this:

```
def function_process_something():
   process_something(condition)
   sleep(1)

while(condition is not reached):
   create a new thread()
   new thread executes function_process_something(condition);
```

Almost every example I have seen uses the thread approach to do parallel jobs, not sequencial ones.
Another thing that makes me confuse is that we dont have a fixed number of threads to be created (it depends on the amount of time the function_process_something has to run to met de condition).

Comment: Why use threads if you don't need parallel execution? Just run the function normally

Comment: I totally agree with you, but this task is for research purpose, it is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no reason why another thread is needed, you can simply do the work on the main thread.

However, if you *do* need the work done in another thread (such as to not affect a GUI thread that must remain responsive) but you still want it done sequentially, the normal approach is to have a single other thread (the worker) running with a work queue.

The main thread simply adds things to the work queue, while the worker thread waits for things to appear on the queue and handles them one at a time.

You don't need to create and destroy threads on the fly in that scenario, just create the worker thread up front. It will basically do nothing unless something is added to the work queue so can be left around until you want to shut down the program.

Spinning up *multiple* threads where each has to wait for the previous to finish before doing anything is possible but really doesn't gain you anything.